# How to add an ImageButton that mimics "my location" -button?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout, android-mapview

My function mimics "my location" -button of Google Maps. I call it using `onClickListner`. I was able to add zoom-out and zoom-in animation to it, but I want it to work like the stock button.

My button:

```
ImageButton Mylocation = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.my_location);
    Mylocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myPosition();
        }
    }
);
```

My function

```
public void myPosition() {
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "  "+latitude+" "+longitude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Longitude = Double.toString(latitude);
        Latitude = Double.toString(longitude);
    }
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng me = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    //MyMarker= mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(me).snippet("My Location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(me));
    CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(me);
    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17);
    mMap.moveCamera(center);
    mMap.animateCamera(zoom);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling ActivityCompat#requestPermissions here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

I want to add my custom button that points to "my location" with zoom- and scroll animation (like the stock button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar in an app that i made.
I used animateCamera and newLatLngZoom like so:

```
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(YourLat,YourLong),yourZoom);
```

you can read more about CameraUpdateFactory [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory)
and about animateCamera [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views)

**edit**

```
public void myPosition() {
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {


            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "  "+latitude+" "+longitude,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Longitude = Double.toString(latitude);
            Latitude = Double.toString(longitude);
        }
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng me = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        //MyMarker= mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(me).snippet("My Location"));

         mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(me),17); //This is where it should be


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    }
```